# jQuery, hovering after animation

Tags: jquery, animation, hover

I'm doing a particular carousel and it has:

- Content
- Next button
- Prev button

And the functionality are:

- When you hover Next or Prev it move of 20px the contents in the direction of the button.
- When you click on the buttons the carousel start the animation.

The code at the moment is rude, full of `if` controls to prevent animations, queues, etc... but it seems to work fine for the moment.

I'm using **jCarousel** as plugin for it and **jQuery easing**.

I prepared a **[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/toroncino/9Et4B/)** for you.

**The BUG**:

There is one bug on it. If you hover the next button (keep your mouse pointer hovered on the next button), click one time, keep always hovered without going out from the button, click one more time. The images are misaligned.

This is caused because after the animation it doesn't recognize anymore to be on the hover state.

How can I fix it?

Comment: The fiddle crashes with `TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating '$firstCarousel.jcarousel')` - seems that the jCarousel-plug-in is missing: `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)`.

Comment: hm, I retryed right now and it works fine...

Comment: I edited the post adding the three file you need to add in JsFiddle if you can not load it.

Comment: I guess the author disabled the access, to save resources, as anybody would link to his location. I'll load them and test it locally this evening.

Comment: if you copy/paste my 3 links it should work because is what I did initially.

Comment: I have updated my **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/toroncino/9Et4B/)** now it should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I edited your fiddle and I hope this is the behavior you expect. And it's also not 'jumpy' anymore like your first version.

I created three new variables:

```
var hovered    = false;
var animating  = false;
var correction = null;
```

The first one stores whether one of the element was hovered, the second one whether the animation is running and the third stores, which correction has to be used (left or ride side).

Than I've updated the functions to keep track of what's happening:

```
$carouselNext.hover(function () {
    if (!animating)
        shunt('-=20');
    hovered = true;
    correction = 'next';
}, function () {
    if (!animating)
        shunt('+=20');
    hovered = false;
    correction = 'next';
});
```

Than I've updated the click-hanlder:

```
$carouselNext.bind('click', function(e) {
    move(0);
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

And the `move()`-function:

```
function move(dir, par) {
    if(!animating) {
        animating = true;
        if(dir == 0) {
            carousel.next();
        } else {
            carousel.prev();
        }
        setTimeout(function() {
            shunt( ( hovered ? '+=0' : ( 'next' == correction ? '+' : '-' ) + '=20' ) );
            animating = false;
        }, 1700);
    }
}
```

Here is the Demo - hope you get everything I've updated.

#### DEMO

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tL8PX/)

Note: The variables from the beginning can be declared within `function carousel_initCallback(carousel)`- somehow it wasn't stored in the fiddle …

Comment: I'm glad I could help - and happy refactoring. :) If the solution fits, you can also award that bounty. :) Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Set `z-index` to 10 or something for your next button, it'll always be on top, also the part where you add the images just to play it safe add `z-index` to 0 or 1 as well.